# Non collection books doesn't appear

Tags: kindle-paperwhite, collections

I have Amazon Kindle paperwhite 2018 edition. I have many collections and many books that I organized nicely in my old device. I always use the "collections" as my homepage. Whenever I download a new book, it used to appear as a non-collection book below the collections so that I can add it into a proper category.

However, I had to replace my Kindle with a new one (again ppw 4). Since then, the non-collection books do not appear on the collection page. Only the collections appear. I don't know if it is a setting or a firmware update but it really makes me lost my track.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

The reason why I didn't see at first place was that my collections were only on the cloud.On the tabs (ALL|DOWNLOADED   and 2 filters on the right corner), I was choosing "collections" instead of "all items" in the first tiny arrow. And the second tiny filter arrow didn't allow me to choose collections (but only recent/title/author). The "collection" selection was faded.

After I downloaded my collections, then choose "all items" on the first filter arrow, "collection" on the second filter arrow, I am able to see my collections as well as my non-sorted books.

I hope it helps for someone else :)